# Cant update table wp_options for wordpress in mariadb

Tags: sql, wordpress, mariadb

Im trying to update wp_options table with a new url and the command just wont work.

```
UPDATE TABLE wp_options 
SET option_value = "http://34.66.147.230" 
WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
```

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "http://34.66.147.230" WHERE option_n
> ame ...' at line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don''t need 'table' keyword and use single-quote for string values:

```
UPDATE wp_options 
SET option_value = 'http://34.66.147.230' 
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Comment: god bless you, friend!

Comment: @HarutaDorin, you should consider marking this as the correct answer. You can read about it here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: (Double quotes and single quotes work equally well.)